# Error in loop in mips

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, matrix-multiplication

Can someone tell me the problem in this one?

```
`#initializing indexes i,j,k
addi $s0, $zero, 0
addi $s1, $zero, 0
addi $s2, $zero, 0

addi $sp, $sp, -16
sw $s0, 0($sp)
sw $s1, 4($sp)
sw $s2, 8($sp)


while1:
bgt $s0,2,exit1


 while2:
 sw $ra, 12($sp)
 bgt $s1,2,exit2
 addi $s1,$s1,1


   while3:
   sw $ra, 12($sp)
   bgt $s2,2,exit3

   mul $t0,$s0,$s0
   add $t1,$t0,$s1
   sll $t2,$t1,3
   add $t3,$t2,$a0
   add $t4,$t2,$a1
   add $t5,$t2,$a2
   ldc1 $f4, ($t3)
   ldc1 $f6, ($t4)
   ldc1 $f8, ($t5)
   mul.d $f8,$f6,$f4
   sdc1 $f8, ($t5)



   addi $s2,$s2,1
   j while3
 addi $s1,$s1,1
 j while2


addi $s0,$s0,1
j while1


exit1:
lw $s0, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 16
jr $ra

exit2:
lw $s1, 4($sp)
jr $ra

exit3:
lw $s1, 8($sp)
jr $ra

addi $t2,$zero,0

while:
beq $t2,24,exit
ldc1 $f2, 0($a2)
li $v0, 3
add.d $f12,$f2,$f0
syscall
addi $t2,$t2,8

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

It tells me Exception occurred at PC=0x000000 , Bad address in text read: 0x0000000 and attempt to execute a non-instruction at 0x80000180..
What i want to do is to multiply matrixes A and B and store the result in a third matrix C. The matrixes A,B and C are in the addresses $a0, $a1 and $a2

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. Also, comment your code especially if you want others to help. Anyway, from a quick glance your `exit` points look suspicious. For one thing, you have no `jal` anywhere, so why the `jr`? Furthermore, only `exit1` seems to restore the stack. You don't set `$a0`-`$a2` anywhere either. Maybe this is not the complete code? See [MCVE].

Comment: No this is not the complete code. I should have posted the whole thing. I found out what is wrong with this part. Can you please tell me why this 
 
 
li $v0 , 7
 
syscall
 
sdc1 $f0 , ($a1) is causing me an exception and an unaligned address?? $a1 is the base address of a matrix and im using doubles

Comment: That must mean `$a1` is not aligned to 8 bytes.

Comment: i reserved space 32 for a 2x2 array. Isnt this ok?

Comment: The space is big enough just not aligned properly. Presumably, since you haven't shown it...

Comment: how am i supposed to do this right?

Comment: Depends on your assembler that you also forgot to mention. Either use directive that allocates 8 bytes which will align them automatically, or use an explicit alignment.